# Type mismatch error with foldLeft method in Scala

Tags: scala, types, foldleft

I have a method that uses foldLeft in Scala.

```
def bitSetToByte(b:collection.BitSet, sh:Int=0) = 
  ((0 /: b) {(acc, input) => acc + (1 << (input - sh))}).toByte
```

The method has two parameters for the anonymous function, so I replaced it with _ by removing formal arguments.

```
def bitSetToByte(b:collection.BitSet, sh:Int=0) = ((0 /: b) {(_ + (1 << (_ - sh))}).toByte
```

The issue is that I have type mismatch error message.

[image]

What might be wrong?

Comment: as a style question, why do you prefer `/:` over `fold...`?

Comment: @Kevin Meredith: To me, it's visually more attractive, it reminds me of a domino that falls onto left side: (START_VALUE) -> /:::::

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When interpreting `_`, the compiler assumes that the anonymous function that the `_` corresponds to is enclosed in the nearest set of parentheses (except for `(_)`). Basically, the compiler interpreted `(_ - sh)` to be `(x => x - sh)`, then complained because you were passing a function to `<<` when it expected an `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

Frist, you messed up with parentheses. I guess you meant something like (also i removed `toByte` for brievity)

```
def bitSetToByte(b:collection.BitSet, sh:Int) = 
  (0 /: b) { (_ + (1 << (_ - sh))) }
```

Second, typer is your firend, you can find out how your code looks after the typer phase of compiler by running scala interpreter with `-Xprint:typer` flag

```
def bitSetToByte(b: scala.collection.BitSet, sh: Int): Int = {
  <synthetic> <artifact> val x$1: Int = 0;
  b./:[Int](x$1)(((<x$2: error>: <error>) => <x$2: error>.<$plus: error>(1.$less$less(((x$3) => x$3.$minus(sh))))))
}
```

lambda expression can be simplified to

```
{ x2 => x2 + (1 << (x3 => x3 - sh)) }
```

which is not what you wanted